# Rails search redirects to incorrect url in subURI hosted production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, production-environment

I have a simple search form which searches the index action of my articles controller. I have deployed my app to a sub URI and when i try searching, it redirects to `domain.eu/articles` instead of `domain.eu/app/articles`. I have made a symlink so every other page is working just fine under the sub URI, so im not sure why this isn't working?

thanks in advance!

my search form is as follows;

```
<%= form_tag("/articles", class: "navbar-search pull-left",  method: :get) do %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search-query span3", placeholder: "search for articles" %>
                        <% end %>
```

article.rb

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, conditions: ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you put in a hard relative URL in here, and on the other places ruby generated urls? What happens if you replace it by "articles_path", which should be defined in your routes.rb?